# How to fix the error "Database/file and session"?

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I have an error in my code. The problem is, the file is not inserting into the database table but inserted to the location folder. I found the error that is by sessions it is not getting the user id from 1st page so, the same thing is happening on the other page. Do any of you give me some advise or help me to easily find the error (removing, updating or something) here is the code:

**1st page - Sign Up Form Page (.php)**

```php
<?php

include "dbConnection.inc";

if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{
error_reporting(1);

    $Email=$_POST['email'];

    $que1="select * from `users` where Email='$Email'";
    $count1=$que1->num_rows;

    if($count1>0)
    {
        echo "<script>
                alert('There is an existing account associated with this email.');
            </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $Name=$_POST["first_name"].' '.$_POST["last_name"];
        $gender=$_POST["gender"];
        $country=$_POST["country"];
        $work=$_POST["work"];
        $password=$_POST["password"];


        $query="INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `Name`, `Email`, `gender`, `country`, `profession/occupation`, `Password`) VALUES (NULL, '$Name', '$Email', '$gender', '$country', '$work', '$password');";
        $cmd=$conn->query($query);

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['tempfbuser']=$Email;

        if ($cmd==true) {
            header("Location:completepro.php");
        } else {
            echo "<script>
                alert('Sign Up not successful, please try again');
            </script>";
            header("Location:signin.php");

        }

    }
}
?>
```

**2nd page - Sign Up Form Page (.php)**

```php
<?php

    session_start();
    include "dbConnection.inc";

    error_reporting(1);
    if(isset($_SESSION['tempfbuser']))
    {
        $user=$_SESSION['tempfbuser'];
        $que1="select * from users where Email='$user' ";
        $rec="$que1->fetch_array();";
        $userid=$rec[0];


                if(isset($_POST['file1']) && ($_POST['file1']=='Upload'))
                {
                    $path = "twigp_users/".$user."/Profile/";
                    $path2 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Post/";
                    $path3 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Cover/";
                    mkdir($path, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path2, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path3, 0, true);

                    $img_name=$_FILES['pro_file']['name'];
                    $img_tmp_name=$_FILES['pro_file']['tmp_name'];
                    $prod_img_path=$img_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($img_tmp_name,"twigp_users/".$user."/Profile/".$prod_img_path);

                    $query="INSERT INTO `user_profile_pic` (`profile_id`, `user_id`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, '$userid', '$img_name');";
                    $cmd=$conn->query($query);
                }


                if(isset($_POST['file2']) && ($_POST['file2']=='Upload'))
                {
                    $path = "twigp_users/".$user."/Profile/";
                    $path2 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Post/";
                    $path3 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Cover/";
                    mkdir($path, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path2, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path3, 0, true);

                    $img_name=$_FILES['cvr_file']['name'];
                    $img_tmp_name=$_FILES['cvr_file']['tmp_name'];
                    $prod_img_path=$img_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($img_tmp_name,"twigp_users/".$user."/Cover/".$prod_img_path);
                        $query="INSERT INTO `user_cover_pic` (`cover_id`, `user_id`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, '$userid', '$img_name');";
                        $cmd=$conn->query($query);
                }

  }

?>
```

Please help me to find out the error, Thanks!!!

Comment: Where you write file upload code?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: Sir, defined below (file upload code) please scroll

Comment: `$rec="$que1->fetch_array();";` won't do what you think. Change it to `$rec = $que1->fetch_array();` (without the quotes). You can't call methods/functions inside double quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks for improving it  "Magnus Eriksson"

Answer (score -2):

Check below code

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include "dbConnection.inc";

    error_reporting(1);
    if(isset($_SESSION['tempfbuser']))
    {
        $user=$_SESSION['tempfbuser'];
        $que1="select * from users where Email='$user' ";
        $rec="$que1->fetch_array();";
        $userid=$rec[0];


                if(isset($_POST['file1']) && ($_POST['file1']=='Upload'))
                {
                    $path = "twigp_users/".$user."/Profile/";
                    $path2 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Post/";
                    $path3 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Cover/";
                    mkdir($path, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path2, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path3, 0, true);

                    $img_name=$_FILES['pro_file']['name'];
                    $img_tmp_name=$_FILES['pro_file']['tmp_name'];
                    $prod_img_path=$img_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($img_tmp_name,"twigp_users/".$user."/Profile/".$prod_img_path);

                    $query="INSERT INTO `user_profile_pic` (`profile_id`, `user_id`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, '$userid', '$img_name');";
                    $cmd=$conn->query($query);
                }


                if(isset($_POST['file2']) && ($_POST['file2']=='Upload'))
                {
                    $path = "twigp_users/".$user."/Profile/";
                    $path2 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Post/";
                    $path3 = "twigp_users/".$user."/Cover/";
                    mkdir($path, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path2, 0, true);
                    mkdir($path3, 0, true);

                    $img_name=$_FILES['cvr_file']['name'];
                    $img_tmp_name=$_FILES['cvr_file']['tmp_name'];
                    $prod_img_path=$img_name;
                    move_uploaded_file($img_tmp_name,"twigp_users/".$user."/Cover/".$prod_img_path);
                        $query="INSERT INTO `user_cover_pic` (`cover_id`, `user_id`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, $userid, $img_name);";
                        $cmd=$conn->query($query);
                }

  }

?>
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation including what the issue was, what you've changed and why it solves the issue. I can also find at least one issue still remaining, the line `$rec="$que1->fetch_array();";`

Comment: _@MagnusEriksson_ thanks for your support and help. The  `$rec="$que1->fetch_array();";` changed to `$rec = $que1->fetch_array();`